# Add codereview.stackexchange.com as an option for closing as off-topic

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, migration, code-review-se

Currently, there are only these Stack Exchange networks as a reason for closing an off-topic question:

- belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com
- belongs on superuser.com
- belongs on tex.stackexchange.com
- belongs on dba.stackexchange.com
- belongs on sharepoint.stackexchange.com

**I recommend** that the http://codereview.stackexchange.com network be added to this list as i've marked several questions as needing to be here, but i have to go to the `Other` option, as opposed to the `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network` option.

Comment: (I just realized that codereview is still in beta.. maybe this is why it's not added yet?)

Comment: Indeed, beta sites cannot be on a migration path

Comment: I like the request, but you're right it isn't available yet because it's in beta.

Comment: @RichardTingle this SE network is heavily used.. i couldn't imagine why this is still in beta.  it has 12,684 questions, 21,813 answers and over 35,000 users.  My recommendation remains :)

Comment: @Servy yep.  go ahead and close. that didn't show up on my google searches. Hopefully this title will show up for users who had the same question i did.

Comment: Incidentally, I still don't understand why text and sharepoint are on the list. I've *never* seen a question on SO that belonged on text or sharepoint. (I have seen a number that belong on codereview; also a number that belong on programmers, and a handful for engineering, math, android, and careers. Never text or sharepoint, though.)

Comment: @neminem They're chosen simply based on number of outgoing migrations, with certain sites that have a very low successful migration rate explicitly removed.

Comment: I just answered my own question about programmers - found an answer from 2012 that it was *too* common a migration path, and was specifically removed because it was getting *too* much garbage dumped on it that programmers.SE then had to clean up. Which makes sense. Would make sense that codereview could be similar to that. 

I'm still curious whether text and sharepoint actually do get much sent their way, though. Seems like I see a lot more engineering/math questions, and those are not at all ambiguous - they're often good engineering/math questions, just not programming.

Comment: @neminem that would also go along with what Jamal said in his answer.  It could be detrimental to the community, because of people not actually being aware of what the codereview site actually is intended for. not going to lie, I have marked questions as to be put on there (hence the motive to write this question) and i still haven't read the help center for CR

Comment: @sircapsalot: While many of our numbers do look good, SE still has reason to believe that we're still not ready for graduation.  Other than migration, lack of enough high-rep users (mainly around 1K to 10K) is holding us back.  If you think you may have something to contribute, I encourage any of you to join CR.  The more avid users we receive, the better.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian dang.. i originally thought your name was `LowerCaseOverflowian` and i would have a smart remark, but if you must know, i've had sircapsalot as a gamertag for more than a decade, and it's a misconception that my name is meant to be "capitalized"  since it's my gamertag that developed in my halo days, i cap a lot of n00bs. hence, sir caps alot.  I cap a lot of n00bs.  ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Code Review mod here.

Grace Note, one of the community managers, has told us that we may still not be added as one of SO's migration paths, even after graduation.  Plus, we see a number of users misleading the OP because they haven't studied both the question and our Help Center, so I often have to correct that user on SO.  Until users become more educated on what we expect, this could *harm* us.

While we're still in beta, users can still flag a moderator for migration.  However, that still creates more work for them as they'll also have to determine if it's not crap and also on-topic.  While there are ways for them to contact the CR mods discreetly, it still creates more work for us.  Overall, it's up to the users to use their best judgment when reading these questions.  Many questions *can* seem borderline, and if that's the case, then flagging is fair.  But if it's obvious that the code *does not work*, then it should stay.

Comment: this makes 100% sense.  see my comment above.

Answer (score 9):

Adding Code Review as a migration path is not only a good thing. See this answer to [What are the advantages of graduation?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/what-are-the-advantages-of-graduation/1576#1576) on Code Review beta.

We often get questions on Code Review that actually belongs on Stack Overflow. I'm afraid having Code Review as a migration path will increase this number of questions.

To make it clear once and for all, a question is on topic on Code Review if:

- The code **works** to the best of the OP's knowledge (this is our most "popular" closing reason)
- The code is written by the one who asks the question
- The question contains code
- It is actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code
- It is desired to be good code and not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar

See our https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic page.

Comment: for my sake and anyone interested then, for clarity, a question pertaining to: `"How do I shorten this snippet into 1 line"` is `on-topic` ?

Comment: @sircapsalot No. See: “*It is desired to be good code and not code-golfing […] or similar*” in the above list.

Comment: yea see.. it's no wonder .. i'm pretty sure 90% of SO users treat the CR network the same as I did then.

Comment: @sircapsalot Depends. Would the snippet still be readable? A better formulation of the question would be: "*Can this be written simpler?*". We can't make any guarantees on how short the code can become.

Comment: the motive for bringing this question up was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389546/initialize-array-with-values-ruby) which I originally marked for migration, but later retracted the vote.

Comment: @sircapsalot That kind of question is one of the many gray areas of Code Review!